# Null pointer exception when trying assign values to hashmap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

```
package com.assignment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;



public class Interview {

private HashMap<String,Integer> stateCounts = null;
private HashMap<String,String> stateNames;
private ArrayList<InputData> inputList = null;


public void loadStateNames(String stateKey,String stateName)
{
    stateNames.put(stateKey, stateName);
}


public static void main(String Args[])
{
    Interview interview = new Interview();
    interview.loadStateNames("NY", "New York");
}
}
```

When I try to pass to strings to loadStateNames. I get a null pointer exception. Can't figure out whats causing this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.assignment.Interview.loadStateNames(Interview.java:41)
at com.assignment.Interview.main(Interview.java:57)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing them. You should do this in the constructor:

```
public Inteview() {
    stateNames = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Also, I doubt you want to give a `null` reference to `stateCounts` and `inputList`. They should also be initialized in the constructor:

```
public Inteview() {
    stateNames = new HashMap<>();
    stateCounts = new HasMap<>();
    inputList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have not initialised the Map ,change it to ::

```
private HashMap<String,String> stateNames = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to initialize your HashMap, change:

```
private HashMap<String,String> stateNames;
```

to:

```
private HashMap<String,String> stateNames = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create an instance:

```
private HashMap<String,String> stateNames = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And for others too. BTW use interface in left side for polymorphism and in Java 7+ you don't need provide types in right side:

```
 private Map<String,String> stateNames = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a class variable like this:

`private HashMap<String,String> stateNames;`

or like this:

`private HashMap<String,String> stateNames = null;`

it is initialized with `null`.

You cannot add keys/values to it when it is `null`.

Either initialize it in a constructor or at declaration time.

`private HashMap<String,String> stateNames = new HashMap<String,String>()`